# Display drop down values from complex JSON using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to angular JS.
I am getting the below JSONArray from a web service call. Requirement is to display the values from the sub array "options" and "text". My drop down should be displayed as that is generated from below HTML:

```
<select>
 <option value="L1" > English </option>
 <option value="L2" > French </option>
 <option value="L3" > Chainese </option>
</select>
```

Here is the code that I have tried using angular ng-options:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="field in json">
   <select tabindex="0" data-ng-options="option.code as option.code as option.text.label for option in field.options" data-ng-model="language_code">
      <option value=""> Select...</option>
   </select>
```

I am unable to access "options" or "text" arrays from the base object.

```
[{
    "id": null,
    "code": "Language",
    "order": 1,
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "L1",
            "order": 1,
            "text": [
                {
                    "language": "eng",
                    "label": "English",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "L2",
            "order": 2,
            "text": [
                {
                    "language": "fre",
                    "label": "French",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "L3",
            "order": 3,
            "text": [
                {
                    "language": "chn",
                    "label": "Chainese",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strange JSON format:
here is working markup and plnker with full solution:http://plnkr.co/edit/OFyfJkTSgpoW2Gwkzzda

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="field in json">
            <select tabindex="0" ng-model="selected" data-ng-options="option.code as option.text[0].label for option in field.options">
                <option value=""> Select...</option>
            </select>
        {{selected}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if we have multiple text array fields(option.text[0].label) is their any alternative way to access label ?

Comment: Not sure what's your question... In json you provided, there is an array field "text", but you have provided just one element. As a result, I have binded it to the first ([0]) element of that array... If you have just one array element, you can flatten the structure and leave code/order/language/label in one level. Or you can add other entries to that array and just access by index, e.g. [1].